# jQuery callback for click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, tomcat

I want to do a simple animation clicking on this link

```
<a id="C" href="http://www.google.com">Make me disappear</a>
```

Callback is

```
$("#C").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide("slow");
});
```

while on [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh4ua/1/) my code works, I am not able to make run this callback on a jsp page. I wrote js code in a different file imported with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lib.js"></script>
```

I am quite sure jQuery and lib.js are being included because from developer tools console (on Chromium) I can make it do the animation; moreover they are both in developer tools' scripts tabs.

Thanks

Comment: check the firebug console tab to see any other script errors exist

Comment: Chances are the DOM is not ready when your code executes. Put it in a DOM ready event handler.

Comment: neither errors not warning, both in firebug console tab and scripts tab..

Comment: @James Allardice We have a winner! @Francesco: Wrap that click function in a `$(function(){ //click function here });` and it'll work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that on jfiddle it's including your jQuery click handler in the page's `onload` function; are you doing that in your lib.js file?

```
$(function() {
    $("#C").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide("slow");
    });
});
```

(Using `$(function() {});` is a shorthand for running that code when the DOM is ready - see the [jQuery .ready() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).)

Or even better:

```
(function($) {
  // do your stuff here
})(jQuery);
```

to be able to handle possible future conflicts.